# SQL Server : build JSON dynamic key

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create object with dynamic key and value with SQL Server.  Currently I have the following query result:

```
[ 
    { "Name": "Ashley", "type": "human" },
    { "Name": "Dori", "type": "cat" }
]
```

and I am looking to build this:

```
[ { "Human": "Ashley" }, { "Cat": "Dori" } ]
```

PS: I'm not sure if it's even possible, but I have no ideas left.

Comment: Do you know all the possible options up front? You can't create dynamic keys without dynamic SQL, but you could include every possible key name in a static query. Sample input would help

Comment: Thanks, good to know that at least I need to create dynamic SQL and yes they are 4 possible keys

Comment: Note that putting data in your JSON names is as inconvenient to consume as it is to create.

Comment: I have a special case, that's why I need it that way, but maybe I had to just return it like this and do it on my own on the backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know every possible combination up front, you can specify them in `CASE` expressions like this

```sql
SELECT
    Human = CASE WHEN t.[type] = 'human' THEN t.Name END,
    Cat =   CASE WHEN t.[type] = 'cat'   THEN t.Name END
-- more options
FROM YourTable t
FOR JSON PATH;
```

---

If you don't know what the possible options are, you will need dynamic SQL.

Try to keep a clear head about which part is static and which is dynamic. Use `PRINT @sql;` to test.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT
' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
'    ' + typeCol + ' = CASE WHEN t.[Type] = ' + typeStr + ' THEN t.Name END'
        AS nvarchar(max)), ',
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
           typeCol = QUOTENAME(UPPER(LEFT(t.[type], 1)) + SUBSTRING(t.[type], 2, LEN(t.[type]))),
           typeStr = QUOTENAME(t.[type], '''')
        FROM YourTable t
    )
) + '
FROM YourTable t
FOR JSON PATH;
';

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;  -- add parameters if necessary
```

Comment: Both answers makes a lot of sense for me, thanks! I was looking for these solutions for hours now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another solution, perhaps for different cases.

In case you already have a generated JSON and you want to transform it, for example:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "value1"
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "value": "value2"
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "value": "value3"
    }
]
```

You can apply this sql script to transform it:

```sql
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '","', '":"')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '"key":', '')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '"value":', '')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '{', '')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '}', '')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, '[', '{')
SET @json = REPLACE(@json, ']', '}')
```

for the example, the result would transform into this:

```json
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: I have a perfectly valid key/value pair like this `"\"{[\"key\",":"][}\":"` now what's going to happen?or